# Raw input not reliably receiving all input

Tags: winapi, raw-input

I'm using raw input in my application to handle global hotkeys, but I'm running in to some funky behavior. Under normal circumstances, if I press the PrintScreen key on my keyboard, my application sees the following raw input events (scancodes):

`2a (down) -> 37 (down) -> 37 (up) -> 2a (up)`

However, if I run a fullscreen game, such as Team Fortress 2, and then press the PrintScreen, I see the following raw input events:

`2a (down) -> 37 (up) -> 2a (up)`

What happened to `37 (down)`? It's like something is swallowing the input event.

Comment: Are you actually talking about scan codes or virtual key codes? They are not the same thing. For instance, 0x2A is the virtual key for `PrntScr` and 0x37 is the virtual key for `7`. Makes me wonder why you would be getting `7` keystrokes at all while pressing `PrntScr`. Are you sure you are not simply capturing something unrelated at the same time `PrntScr` is pressed? Remember, you are getting **raw** input, afterall.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about scan codes (i.e. the MakeCode in RAWKEYBOARD). 0x37 becomes VK_SNAPSHOT when I translate it to a virtual key code, hence the problem of me not being able to detect the key down event for VK_SNAPSHOT. And yes, the two input events are definitely related to me pressing PrtScrn/SysRq key on my keyboard, not something else.

Comment: Are you using `GetRawInputData()` or `GetRawInputBuffer()` to get the message data?  Did you check with Spy++ or similar tool to see that you really receive only 3 `WM_INPUT` messages and not 4?

Comment: I'm using GetRawInputData(). I only receive 3 WM_INPUT messages. Like I said, it works in the general case but then in certain situations, such as when running a game, it doesn't work the same way anymore.

Comment: Well, considering the events are coming directly from the hardware and delivered directly to your app, the hardware is likely only generating 3 events in the first place, and nothing is being "swallowed" (I'm not sure if raw input CAN be swallowed, unless something in your app is discarding the `WM_INPUT` messages before you process them). Try switching to `GetRawInputBuffer()` and see if it also reports only 3 events or not.